# On Spree how do you add your own custom stylesheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Im using spree 3.0.0 and i want to add my own stylesheet (sass file) how do i get spree to read the file in? I have read that you can deface and override certain files but i don't know how you get add new ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stylesheets for the admin backend customization goes in `vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend` while the stylesheets for  front-end customization goes in `vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend`.